# Serialized and deserialize HTML style tag with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, serialization, deserialization

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Save/copy HTML snippet in one place, paste it in another place and have it de-serealized into an analogous DOM

**How do I do serialization now**

- Call `element.outerHTML` on a container element

  - I've also tried using `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element)` with the same result

**The issue**

When I serialize `style` nodes that contain the css like:

```css
.a > .b {
  color: red
}
```

They actually get serialized like

```
.a &gt; .b {
  color: red
}
```

Which is not a valid CSS and so does not get parsed properly.

The problem with greater sign is the only one I observe, but it makes me wonder about other potential serialization issues.

**Question**: How do I get serialize the style nodes in a way that does not break CSS in them?

Comment: that is what I'm doing, as I say in "How do I do serialization now" section 

Comment: here is a full an example of the serialized output, let me know if you manage to make it display properly ;) https://gist.github.com/Stvad/40af2951ddfe06134b341424b5a57fe1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that this has to do with creating the style node dynamically on a new document.

The easiest reproduction is as follows:

```js
const doc = new Document()

const style = doc.createElement('style')
style.textContent = '.a>.b { color: red; }'

console.log(style.outerHTML)
```

Which yields `<style>.a&gt;.b {color:red}</style>`

It seems that being part of actively rendered document/or just generally being added to a document and not just created using it has some side-effect on the style node, which causes it to be serialized properly though. So now I do the following instead as a workaround, which is a bit ugly but works:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<html><head></head><body></body></html>', 'text/html')


const style = doc.createElement('style')
style.textContent = '.a>.b { color: red; }'

doc.body.append(style)

console.log(style.outerHTML)

doc.body.removeChild(style)
```

Which produces an appropriately serialized `<style>.a>.b { color: red; }</style>`

Now this solves my problem, but I'd still really like to understand **what is happening here** in more detail (e.g. what is the side-effect exactly and how/when is it triggered), so would appreciate  comments on that!